# trying to do something super cool on my web site

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

how to do that if user did not did anything on the website for a set amount of time the website will log out him?

is it from the c# page?

how can i tocount the time sincethe last touch on something?

and how can i alert it?

plss help

i want to add it here:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Conect"]!=null)
        {
            if (!(bool)Session["Conect"])
            {
                Response.Redirect("Must-Had.aspx", true);
            }
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("Must-Had.aspx", true);

        if (Session["val"]!=null)
        {
            if ((bool)Session["val"])
            {
                limission4.Visible = true;
                mission4.InnerText =(string)Session["tit"];
            }
        }
        if (Session["val2"] != null)
        {
            if ((bool)Session["val2"])
            {
                limission5.Visible = true;
                mission5.InnerText = (string)Session["tit2"];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this somewhere between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout("window.close();", 3000);


window.onscroll = function (e) {  
window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout("window.close();", 3000);
} 
</script>
```

You can change the "`3000`" to whatever amount of time you want the page to last.

You can also change the "`window.close();`" to whatever you want the page to do when the time runs out. The "`window.close();`" command will just close the page.

Comment: how can i alert and then redirect?

Comment: To alert you will need to set up some sort of div that will pop up after a certain amount of time. To redirect you will need to change the `window.close();` to something like `Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx", true);`